# Windows freezes due to excessive memory allocation of 64-bit process

Tags: c++, windows, memory, memory-management, administrator

When I run a 64-bit program on Windows (version 7 and up) and the program tries to allocate too much memory (close to 100% of physical memory) the system grinds to a halt. If I don't catch it in time and kill the offending process the system will become unresponsive and a hard reboot is required. Obviously the program shouldn't try to allocate so much memory, but bugs can happen and I want to protect the other running processes from the effects of any such bugs in the code I'm working on when testing/debugging. (This was less of a problem in 32-bits because the logical memory limit provided a safety net from system-wide memory choke.)

So I have two questions:

- Can a process limit its memory consumption? Is there a system call in Windows that can set a memory limit, so that allocations beyond the limit will fail instead of crash the whole system?
- Alternatively, is there any way to set a system-wide per-process memory limit or to set a limit for a particular application?

Here's a sample code that causes my computer to freeze. It was compiled with Visual Studio 10.0 in x86_amd64 configuration and I ran it on a laptop with 16 GB RAM under Windows 8.1. It attempts to allocate 32 GB of memory. **Run at your own risk.**

```
int main(void)
{
    const static int csNumArrays=10, csArraySize=800000000;
    int i, j, **p;

    p=new int*[csNumArrays];
    for (i=0; i<csNumArrays; ++i)
    {
        p[i]=new int[csArraySize];
        for (j=0; j<csArraySize; ++j)
            p[i][j]=j;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/clinth/2012/10/11/can-a-process-be-limited-on-how-much-physical-memory-it-uses/

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks, but this isn't what I need. Just to clarify: I'm not trying to manipulate the physical memory limit of the process (aka "working set"), I am trying to limit the size of the virtual memory of the process. And I'm trying to do it from within the program when the source code is available (e.g., through a system call) or externally through an administrative tool when the source code is not available.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Thanks for your reply. You say that it shouldn't crash the entire system, have you tried it yourself? It consistently happened to me on three different occasions, all on different machines with different versions of Windows in completely different circumstances involving different software. It also happened to me on Linux, but I know how to solve it there. I hardly believe this was just a coincidence.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Thanks Harry for trying to help. Perhaps 12 GB on an 8 GB machine isn't putting it under enough stress. Try to double or triple that. Anyway, I added my code which causes the computer to freeze. Just tried it now and had to do a hard reboot after the computer was unresponsive for 30 minutes. Even if eventually it would have recovered, I think it should be clear why I would like to instate some kind of safety measure that will prevent a rogue program from disabling the computer for an extended period, especially if that rogue program is my own (imperfect) program.

Comment: My Windows 7 test machine becomes only intermittently unresponsive when running your program.  But Windows 8 might be more severely affected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably the best option is for the process to put itself into a [Windows job](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682409(v=vs.85).aspx) and apply the [ProcessMemoryLimit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684156(v=vs.85).aspx) option.  (One catch: this won't work if the process is already in a job, e.g., because it is being run as a startup script or scheduled task.)  You can also use the same technique to limit the memory usage of another process that you launch (or that is already running).

Alternatively, you could try spinning up a thread that uses [CreateResourceMemoryNotification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366541(v=vs.85).aspx) to detect a low physical memory condition and terminate the process.  But you may find this is subject to false positives.  (This should certainly not be left in production code.)

Answer (score 3):

Based on Harry Johnston's helpful answer I put together a bit of code that can be added at the beginning of a program to impose a limit on that program's memory allocation as a factor of the physical memory size.

```
ULONGLONG aMemSize;
HANDLE aJob=::CreateJobObject(NULL, NULL);
JOBOBJECT_EXTENDED_LIMIT_INFORMATION aLimit;

    // Get physical memory and set process memory limit to 75% of physical memory
GetPhysicallyInstalledSystemMemory(&aMemSize);
aMemSize*=size_t(768);                      // convert kb to bytes and apply 75% factor
memset(&aLimit, 0, sizeof(aLimit));
aLimit.BasicLimitInformation.LimitFlags=JOB_OBJECT_LIMIT_PROCESS_MEMORY;
aLimit.ProcessMemoryLimit=aLimit.PeakProcessMemoryUsed=aLimit.JobMemoryLimit=
                                                aLimit.PeakJobMemoryUsed=aMemSize;
::SetInformationJobObject(aJob, JobObjectExtendedLimitInformation, &aLimit, sizeof(aLimit));
::AssignProcessToJobObject(aJob, ::GetCurrentProcess());
```